# SimpleAdapter и Picasso

Tags: picasso, android, listview, java, adapter

Добрый день. Использую SimpleAdapter для динамического заполнения ListView. В ListView имеется несколько TextView и ImageView, изображение к которому "загружается" с помощью библиотеки Picasso. Но по факту картинка не грузится, и в LogCat куча вот такой вот дребедени:

`resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator`

Подскажите, как исправить. Пробовал также использовать библиотеку Universal Image Loader, тот же результат.

Код для наглядного примера. (Буду также благодарен за указания ошибок в коде, я только учусь. )))):

```
public class LoadActivity extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList <HashMap<String, Object>> listItems;
    private static final String TEXT1 = "text1";
    private static final String TEXT2 = "text2";
    private static final String IMAGE = "image";

    HashMap<String, Object> hm;

    MyTask rt;
    ProgressBar pb;
    ListView lv;

    public static RosterActivity newInstance() {
        RosterActivity fragment = new RosterActivity();
        return fragment;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_load, container, false);

        pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressRoster);
        lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.loadList);

        listItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

        rt = new MyTask();
        rt.execute();

        return view;
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ...............
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            for (Element parseData : parseBlocks) {
                ...................
                hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put(POSITIONS, text1);
                hm.put(NAME, text2);
                hm.put(COUNTRY, Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://javatechig.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/UniversalImageLoader-620x405.png"));
                listItems.add(hm);
                .........................
            }
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), 
                    listItems, 
                    R.layout.list_item_my, new String[]{
                    TEXT1,
                    TEXT2,
                    IMAGE
            }, new int[]{
                    R.id.text1,
                    R.id.text2,
                    R.id.image});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта проблема решается с помощью кастомного адаптера. Для поля image передавайте просто ссылку на изображение. С пикассо особо не работал, так что за 100% правильность кода не поручусь, но смысл вы должны понять

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> results;
private Context context;

public MyAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data, int resource,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    this.results = data;
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = view;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_my, null);
    }
    TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text1.setText(results.get(position).get("text1").toString());
    TextView text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    text2.setText(results.get(position).get("text2").toString());
    ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
    Picasso.with(context).load(results.get(position).get("image").toString()).into(image);
    return v;
}
}
```